# @react-native-community/geolocation causes compilation error for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, geolocation

**My system:**

```
MacOS: Big Sur
XCode: Version 12.5.1 (12E507)
iOS Simulator: iPhone 8 (iOS 14.5)
Node: v16.10.0
```

I created fresh React Native project:

```
npx react-native@latest init MyFreshProject
```

It was created successfully.

```
npm run ios
```

It runs successfully on iOS Simulator.

Then I installed `@react-native-community/geolocation` (^3.0.6). I added the following code into `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

and in `App.tsx` added the following code:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
...
...
useEffect(() => {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
}, []);
```

After these changes, I ran `npm run ios` again and build fails with the output:

```
...
...
...
/Users/aberikashvili/Documents/.../MyFreshProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/ios/RNCGeolocation.mm:393:23: error: property 'sourceInformation' not found on object of type 'CLLocation *'
mocked = location.sourceInformation.isSimulatedBySoftware;
                  ^
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/aberikashvili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFreshProject-cviktleltpvwpcdkzpdqowhphiwn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNCGeolocation.o /Users/aberikashvili/Documents/.../MyFreshProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/ios/RNCGeolocation.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I tried to comment out `Geolocation` usage in `App.tsx`, but build still failing.

Any ideas?

P.S. This issue is torturing me few days already

Comment: Did you run pod install after adding the library?

Comment: @Abe yes, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was that, `CLLocation Source Information` is supported by iOS 15+, and iOS 15 itself needs XCode 13+ (mine was 12).

So, the solution was to update MacOS from `Big Sur` to `Ventura`, install latest XCode and it worked